# I have done port forwarding private to public IP BUT in public IP IT will not render the geoip.js but it will work fine on local address

Tags: java, javascript, wicket

HERE IS My Code What I Have done 
I have done port forwarding private to public IP BUT in public IP IT will not render the geoip.js but it will work fine on  local address

```
http://61.12.124.234:8080/zipgrocery/home(my public ip)
```

it will not render geoip.js and work fine in local address.
geoip.js give the city name and runtime when user get login

```
basepage.html



<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.toastmessage.css"
    type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/NewHomePage_style.css">

<!-- sliderman.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sliderman.1.3.6.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sliderman.css" />
<!-- /sliderman.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//j.maxmind.com/js/geoip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.toastmessage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/zipjs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.inputhints.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" src="/tweet/jquery.tweet.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {

            /*  $("#city-dropdown").click(function(){
                    $("#user-acc-drop").hide();
                    $("#drop").slideToggle();
                });
                */
                $("#city-dropdown-text").val(geoip_city())
                var text = $("#city-dropdown-text").val();
                $("#txtCityName").val(text);  

                $("#user-acc").click(function(){
                    $("#drop").hide();
                    $("#user-acc-drop").slideToggle();
                });

                $("#pageHolder").click(function(){
                    closeMenu();                    
                });

                $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
                    if (e.which == 27) {
                        closeMenu();
                    }
                }); 

                $("#city-dropdown-text").click(function() {
                var text = $("#city-dropdown-text").val();
                    $("#txtCityName").val(text);                
                });

                $("#city-dropdown-text").keyup(function(e) {
                        var text = $("#city-dropdown-text").val();
                        $("#txtCityName").val(text);                
                });

                $('#city-dropdown-text-autocomplete').live('click', function() {
                    var text = $("#city-dropdown-text").val();
                    $("#txtCityName").val(text);                
                });

                documentReady()
            });     

            function removeClass(){
                $("#drop li").removeClass("current");
            }

            function closeMenu(){
                $("#drop").hide();
                $("#user-acc-drop").hide();
            }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="row-fluid mainContain">

        <div class="span12 head">
            <div class="span3 logoo">
                <a href="#" wicket:id="lnkHomeIcon"><img
                    src="images/zip-grocery-logo.png" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="span6 navBar ">
                <div class="span1 menu">GET THE APP!</div>
                <div class="span1 menu3" wicket:id="lnkRegister">SIGN UP</div>
                <div class="span1 menu2" id="" wicket:id="lnkLogin">LOGIN</div>

                <div class="span1 menu2" wicket:id="lnkUser"
                    style="pointer-events: none;">
                    <span class="link-user" wicket:id="lbUser"></span>
                </div>

                <span class="user-acc" id="user-acc" wicket:id="lnkuseracc">
                    <img src="images/imgArrow.png" />
                    <ul id="user-acc-drop" class="arrow_box2"
                        style="display: none; position: absolute;">
                        <li wicket:id="lnkSettings"><a href="">Setting</a></li>
                        <li wicket:id="lnkLogout"><a href="">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </span> <span class="span5 text" id="city-dropdown"> <input
                    type="text" wicket:id="txtzipcode" id="city-dropdown-text"
                    class="home-search-zip"> <!-- <span wicket:id="currentLoc" class="city-name">HOBOKEN, NJ(7030)</span> 
                        <img src="images/imgArrow.png"/>
                        <ul id="drop" class="arrow_box"> 
                            <li wicket:id="Hobokencity">Hoboken, NJ</li>
                            <li wicket:id="JerseyCity">Jersey City, NJ</li>
                            <li wicket:id="MidtownNYC">Midtown, NYC</li>
                        </ul>-->
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- 
                repalce part by pages
             -->
        <div id="pageHolder">
            <wicket:child></wicket:child>
        </div>
        <div wicket:id="login">
            <div wicket:id="loginPanel" />
        </div>

        <!-- footer start -->


        <div class="span12 footer_bar">
            <div class="span12 footer_Pad">
                <div class="span12 browse_by">Browse By</div>
                <div class="span12 city">City</div>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="foot-link" wicket:id="lnkHoboken">Hoboken,
                                    NJ</span></td>
                            <td><span class="foot-link" wicket:id="lnkJersey">Jersey
                                    City, NJ</span></td>
                            <td><span class="foot-link" wicket:id="lnkMidtown">Midtown,
                                    NYC</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <hr>
                <div class="span12 cuisine">Cuisine / Specialty Store</div>
                <table class="cuisineStore">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Asian</td>
                            <td>Italian</td>
                            <td>Pharmacy</td>
                            <td>Groceries</td>
                            <td>Pizzeria</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>BBQ</td>
                            <td>Deli</td>
                            <td>Liqour Store</td>
                            <td>Middle Eastern</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <hr>
                <div class="span12 links_section">
                    <div class="span2 links_header">
                        <a href="" wicket:id="lnkAbout">About Us</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2 links_header add">
                        <a href="">Advertise Here</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2 links_header getList">
                        <a href="">Get Listed</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2 links_header work-with">
                        <a href="" wicket:id="lnkCareers">Work With Us</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2 links_header faq">
                        <a href="" wicket:id="lnkFaq">FAQ</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2 links_header contac-us">
                        <a href="" wicket:id="lnkContactUs ">Contact Us</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="span12 second_row">
                    <div class="span3 secondrow_containt">
                        <a href="">All Rights reserved to ZipGrocery.</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3 secondrow_containt2">
                        <a href="">Privacy Policy.</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span2 secondrow_containt3">
                        <a href="">Terms and Conditions.</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- footer end -->

    </div>

</body>
</html>


basepage.java



package com.zipgrocery.pages;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.wicket.Component;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.OnChangeAjaxBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxFallbackLink;
import org.apache.wicket.behavior.Behavior;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.autocomplete.AutoCompleteTextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainer;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link;
import org.apache.wicket.model.AbstractReadOnlyModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters;

import com.visural.wicket.component.dialog.Dialog;
import com.zipgrocery.ZipSession;
import com.zipgrocery.data.Zip;
import com.zipgrocery.panels.LoginPanel;
public class ZBasePage extends WebPage{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4591920443207458425L;
    private AjaxFallbackLink lnkLogin;
    private Link<String> lnkLogout;
    private Link<String> lnkOrders;
    private AjaxFallbackLink lnkRegister;
    private Link<String> lnkUser;
    private Link<String> lnkSettings;
    private Link<String> lnkMerchantEdit;
    private Link<String> lnkMerchantLogout;
    private Link<String> lnkAbout;
    private Link<String> currentcity;
    private Dialog loginBox;
    private LoginPanel loginPanel;
    private AjaxFallbackLink lnkHoboken,lnkJersey,lnkMidtown;
    private AjaxFallbackLink Hobokencity,JerseyCity,MidtownNYC;
    private List<Component> componentList = new ArrayList<Component>();
    private String zipcode="07030";
    public ZBasePage() {

        //navigation for logo
        add(new Link<String>("lnkHomeIcon") {

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
                params.set("zipcode", ZipSession.get().getAttribute("currentZip"));
                setResponsePage(ZHomePage.class, params);
            }
        });

        /*render all location or zip 
        List<String> zoneName=Zip.getZoneNames();
        for(int i=0;i<zoneName.size();i++){
            System.out.println(zoneName.get(i));
        }*/

        // add search field
        final AutoCompleteTextField<String> txtZipcode = new AutoCompleteTextField<String>(
                        "txtzipcode", new Model<String>() {
                            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                            @Override
                            public String getObject() {
                                return getZipcode();
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void setObject(String object) {
                                setZipcode(object);
                            }

                        }) {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    protected Iterator<String> getChoices(String input) {
                        return Zip.getUniqueZipsAndZones(input).iterator();
                    }
                };

        add(txtZipcode)

;   


                        //navigation links edit by 
        lnkAbout = new Link<String>("lnkAbout") {

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                setResponsePage(FaqPage.class);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isVisible() {
                return !ZipSession.get().MerchantisValid();
            }
        };
        lnkAbout.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        add(lnkAbout);



    /*   final Model<String> lnkuseraccmodel = new Model<String>(); 
         final WebMarkupContainer lnkuseracc=new WebMarkupContainer("lnkuseracc",lnkuseraccmodel);
         lnkuseracc.setOutputMarkupId(true);
         lnkuseracc.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

         add(lnkuseracc);
    */        

        final WebMarkupContainer lnkuseracc = new WebMarkupContainer("lnkuseracc");
        lnkuseracc.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        add(lnkuseracc);

        if(ZipSession.get().getCustomer() != null)
            lnkuseracc.setVisible(true);
        else
            lnkuseracc.setVisible(false);

        lnkUser = new Link<String>("lnkUser") {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
            }
        };

        lnkUser.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(lnkUser);


        //current user
        lnkUser.add(new Label("lbUser", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {

            @Override
            public String getObject() {

            if(lnkuseracc!=null && ZipSession.get().getCustomer() != null)
             lnkuseracc.setVisible(true);
            return ZipSession.get().getCustomer() == null ? "" : ZipSession.get().getCustomer().getEmail();
            }
        }).setEscapeModelStrings(false));
        lnkUser.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        //current city

        /*currentcity.add(new Label("currentcity", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {
            @Override
            public String getObject() {

            return " ";
            }
        }).setEscapeModelStrings(false));
        currentcity.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(currentcity);*/

        //logout link
        lnkLogout = new Link<String>("lnkLogout") {

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                ZipSession.get().invalidate();
                setResponsePage(ZHomePage.class);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isVisible() {
                return ZipSession.get().isValid();
            }
        };
        lnkLogout.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        lnkLogout.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        lnkuseracc.add(lnkLogout);

        lnkSettings = new Link<String>("lnkSettings") {

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                setResponsePage(CustomerProfilePage.class);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isVisible() {
                return ZipSession.get().isValid();
            }
        };
        lnkSettings.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        lnkSettings.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        lnkuseracc.add(lnkSettings);

        /*login code start here */
        lnkLogin = new AjaxFallbackLink("lnkLogin") {

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
                ajaxRequestTarget.add(loginPanel);
                ajaxRequestTarget.add(loginBox);
                loginBox.open(ajaxRequestTarget);
                ajaxRequestTarget.appendJavaScript("documentReady()");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isVisible() {
                return !ZipSession.get().isValid();
            }
        };
        add(lnkLogin);


        lnkRegister = new AjaxFallbackLink<String>("lnkRegister") {

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
                setResponsePage(CustomerProfilePage.class);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isVisible() {
                return !ZipSession.get().isValid();
            }
        };
        add(lnkRegister);

        //login dialog
        loginBox = new Dialog("login");
        loginPanel = new LoginPanel("loginPanel", loginBox, getRefreshables());
        loginPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        loginBox.add(loginPanel);
        add(loginBox);
        /*login code end here*/

        /*footer menu code*/
        lnkHoboken = new AjaxFallbackLink("lnkHoboken") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
                mearchentListByCity("Hoboken");
            }
        };
        add(lnkHoboken);

        lnkJersey = new AjaxFallbackLink("lnkJersey") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
                mearchentListByCity("Jersey City");
            }
        };
        add(lnkJersey);

        lnkMidtown = new AjaxFallbackLink("lnkMidtown") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
                mearchentListByCity("Midtown NYC");
            }
        };
        add(lnkMidtown);

        //contact us link
        add(new Link<String>("lnkContactUs") {

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                setResponsePage(ContactUsPage.class);
            }
        });
        //end of contact us

        //faq link
        add(new Link<String>("lnkFaq") {

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                setResponsePage(FaqPage.class);
            }
        });
        //end of faq
        //career link
        add(new Link<String>("lnkCareers") {

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                setResponsePage(CareerPage.class);
            }
        });
        //end of career

        /*code for city selection*/
        String defaultCity = "Hoboken";
        if(ZipSession.get().getZipcode()!=null && ZipSession.get().getZipcode().length()>0){
            if(ZipSession.get().getZipcode().equals("07030")){
                defaultCity ="HOBOKEN";
            }else{
                defaultCity = ZipSession.get().getZipcode();
            }
        }
       /* final Model<String> model = new Model<String>(defaultCity); 
        final Label currentCityLbl=new Label("currentLoc",model);
        currentCityLbl.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        currentCityLbl.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        add(currentCityLbl);

        Hobokencity = new AjaxFallbackLink("Hobokencity") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
                //mearchentListByCity("Hoboken");
                    ZipSession.get().setZipcode("Hoboken");
                    model.setObject("Hoboken");
                    currentCityLbl.setDefaultModel(model);
                    ajaxRequestTarget.addComponent(currentCityLbl); 
            }
        };
        JerseyCity = new AjaxFallbackLink("JerseyCity") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
                //mearchentListByCity("Jersey City");
                ZipSession.get().setZipcode("Jersey City");
                model.setObject("Jersey City");
                currentCityLbl.setDefaultModel(model);
                ajaxRequestTarget.addComponent(currentCityLbl);
            }
        };
        MidtownNYC = new AjaxFallbackLink("MidtownNYC") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget ajaxRequestTarget) {
                //mearchentListByCity("Midtown NYC");
                ZipSession.get().setZipcode("Midtown NYC");
                model.setObject("Midtown NYC");
                currentCityLbl.setDefaultModel(model);
                ajaxRequestTarget.addComponent(currentCityLbl);
            }
        };
        add(Hobokencity);
        add(JerseyCity);
        add(MidtownNYC);*/
  }

    protected void mearchentListByCity(String city){
        PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters();
        try{
            pageParameters.add("citySearch",true);
            pageParameters.add("zipcode",city);
        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setResponsePage(HomePage.class, pageParameters);
    }

    protected final List<Component> getRefreshables() {

        for (Component c : componentList) {
            if (c != null) {
                c.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                c.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
            }
        }
        componentList.add(lnkLogout);
        componentList.add(lnkSettings);
        componentList.add(lnkLogin);
        componentList.add(lnkRegister);
        /*componentList.add(lnkOrders);*/
        componentList.add(lnkUser);
        return componentList;
    }

    public String getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }

    public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

}
```

help me out from this...........................

Comment: thanxs joachim it works...

Answer (score 0):

If I am calling the URL j.maxmind.com/js/geoip.js (without the double slashes like you have in your code), I'm just getting a site saying "Unauthorized".

After browsing a bit the [documentation](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/javascript/) of the site, you will find that each domain has to be registered to use this service. And I guess you just need to register your public IP / domain (or whatever they want to have).